# Correctly setting up Java exception handling

Tags: java, exception, throw

I've been attempting to write Java exception handlers for a while now, have tried multiple methods and have even visited/read through Oracle's "The Java Tutorials" and I still cannot get it straight.  I'm unsure what I am doing wrong.  I have a given class (TooLowException) for the exception that I am trying to use.  In the method I am attempting to use it in I am using an argument that I need to catch if it is less than zero.

```
    public int func(int num) throws TooLowException {
       int blah = num + 1;
       if ( blah < 0) {
           return blah;
       }
       else {
            String error = "Input is too low.";
            throw new TooLowException(error);
       }
     }
```

This is the exception class:

```
    public class TooLowException extends Exception {
        public TooLowException(String response) {
            super(response);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error in Oracle "Unhandled Exception type TooLowException".  I've also attempted the try-catch method as well, but it also doesn't work for me.  Hopefully this is enough information for someone to point out what I'm doing incorrectly.  I need to be set right in my ways of exception handling.

Comment: Where is the `try/catch` code.?

Comment: You need to handle this exception in the code which calls `func(int)`;

Comment: either you need to add try catch block in your else part or you have to  add try/catch in the part of code where you are calling func(num).

Comment: can you post your TooLowException class ?

Comment: http://www.java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/ Link will provide you more clear explanation of creating custom exception class

Comment: @AmanArora Your threshold of boredom must be exceptionally low. The question has only been here for six minutes.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you're **using** `func`?

Comment: the method looks alright, are you calling the method func and not handling the exception there? the calling method should either try/catch your custom exception or rethrow it.

Comment: I was reading through the java2novice.com page and I tried the immediate if-check-throw in my 'func' method and it doesn't work.  still the same error.

Comment: Just a side note: The function is given a number, increaes it by one and if it is still _smaller_ than 0 it is ok, but if not the input was _too low_ ? Like you give it -5 and it will return -4 but if you give it 0 it will throw "TooLowException"?

Comment: @looser This is a professional forum. Kindly conduct yourself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from what info you've given, it seems that you need to have a try/catch block somewhere in your code.  Basically somewhere in your application that func(int) method is being called, or needs to be called if you're running into a compiler error telling you the "Unhandled Exception type TooLowException."  General rule for exceptions is Handle/Catch or Declare.  This can be broken down like this:

- Handle/Catch:  If you choose to handle the exception, then the "throws" declaration should be removed from the method signature ("public int func(int num) throws TooLowException" becomes "public int func(int num)").  The idea behind this approach is that you as the programmer intend to handle this type of exception because it's specific enough to the method that you don't want external code to have to worry about handling the exception outside of the scope of the method.  This requires that you "handle" the exception yourself, by using a try/catch block.
- Declare:  This is the method you went with.  You are stating that whatever class uses this function has the burden of handling the exception with the try/catch block.  This would be used if the method you wrote is generic enough that many different applications can use it and that handling the exception should be application specific, i.e., it's up to other developers to handle it in their own way.  Some people like to just log things, others like to have a different control flow execute upon receiving certain exceptions.

Here's what works, sorry if it basically answers an exercise you needed to do, but it's in the interest of helping you!  Please take time to understand what is happening here:

```
public class YourClassThisStuffIsIn {

    public static int func(int num) throws TooLowException {
           int blah = num + 1;
           if ( blah < 0) {
               return blah;
           }
           else {
                String error = "Input is too low.";
                throw new Exception(error);
           }
         }

    public static void main(String[] commandlineArgument){
        try {
            YourClassThisStuffIsIn.func(3);
        } catch (TooLowException tle){
            System.out.println("Caught " + e);
        }
    }  
}
```

When you click run in your IDE, or you run through the console, the JVM looks for the main method with the correct signature.  In this case it finds it, and it executes the main method.  First line is a try, meaning the JVM has to prepare itself for the possibility of a problem in the application, allowing it to recover in case an exception is thrown.  In this case, the only exception that can be thrown is a TooLowException, which you have written how to handle it inside the catch block.  Your way of handling it is simply printing the stack trace out, which is fine I think in this situation.

I've changed your example slightly, making your method static just so it's quicker to write.  I also suspect that the intent is that the commandLineArgument is meant to be the number passed into the func(int) method, so in that case you're looking at the func method to look like func(Integer.parseInt(commandlineArgument[0])).

Bonus points for you is noticing that parseInt throws a NumberFormatException too, but you will of course remember that java.lang.RuntimeException and its subclasses aren't checked exceptions so there is no requirement to catch them, though it is good practice!

Comment: Putting the try/catch around the call in main is what I was failing to do… I sincerely hope I remember this.  For some reason every time I've looked up informations about exceptions I've never caught on to main 'trying to catch' the method's 'throw'; I kept thinking that those were meant to stay within the method.  Your bullet explanations were very helpful as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it can be hard sometimes to envision the whole process chain.  Basically any checked exception that is thrown needs to be caught somewhere, be it in the method that throws it (think Ground Zero) or all the way to the beginning of the call stack.  Your func method can either have the try/catch in it, or throw the exception to have the method that calls func catch it.